# snapshot.ConnectionState is always waiting in the FutureBuilder using provider package

Tags: flutter, provider

I am using cloud firestore as a backend and the provider package for state management for my app. I have a BooksProvider class (ChangeNotifierProvider) which I use to fetch, add, update and delete data. In this class, I have an async method to fetch data from cloud firestore.

```
 Future<void> fetchAndSetData() async {
    try {
      final response = await bookCollection.getDocuments();
      List<Book> loadedBooks = [];
      final querySnapshot = response.documents;
      if (querySnapshot.isEmpty) {
        return;
      }
      querySnapshot.forEach((book) {
        loadedBooks.add(
          Book(
              id: book.documentID,
              title: book.data['title'],
              description: book.data['description'],
              image: book.data['image'],
              rate: book.data['rate'],
              category: CategoryName.values[book.data['category_index']],
              date: book.data['date'],
              price: book.data['price'],
              isFree: book.data['isFree'],
              isFavorite: book.data['isFavorite']),
        );
      });
      _booksList = loadedBooks;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

I am trying to use it with the future builder but it doesn't work as it is always stuck in ConnectionState.waiting case.

```
class BooksScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    final booksData = Provider.of<BooksProvider>(context);
//    final books = booksData.booksList;
//    final _noContent = Center(child: Text('No books are available.'));

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Provider.of<BooksProvider>(context).fetchAndSetData(),
      builder: (ctx, dataSnapshot) {
        switch (dataSnapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return Text('waiting'); //always returning waiting
            break;
          case ConnectionState.done:
            return Text('done');
            break;
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Text('none');
            break;
          default:
            return Text('default');
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what might be wrong, I tried to change the return type of the async method so that it returns a list of Book but it didn't work. I also used if statement instead of the switch case and the same thing kept happening.

In addition, I tried it with if (dataSnapshot.hasdata) as it is suggested by on of the answers, and it worked!, but i want to use a spinner while waiting and when i tried it, the same problem occurred again.

I tried the same method with another approach where i used stateful widget and didChangeDependencies() method to fetch the data and it worked just fine, and I am trying future builder approach because I don't know how to handle errors with didChangeDependencies() approach.

so if you please can help me with the future builder or error handling with the latter approach. Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you getting any exception, add a print statement in the catch block and check.

Comment: I don't get any error or exception, and when I print dataSnapshot, i get flutter: AsyncSnapshot<String>(ConnectionState.waiting, data, null) infinitely, as I said the method works fine with other approaches, but the return type might be the problem as i use void inside a futurebuilder

Answer (score 1):

Use `dataSnapshot.hasData` instead of `dataSnapshot.connectionState`

Comment: thank you! it worked but what if i want to use CircularProgressIndicator() while waiting for the data?

Comment: if dataSnapshot.hasData is false, then you can show a circular progress indicator.